# Installling fails with no error messages

Tags: 7

I installed Drupal 7 on linuxMint 17.1 localhost using the install wizard. Submitting the database configuration page leads to a white screen and nothing else happens.

Looking at the database I could see some data though.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical white screen of death issue, ways to debug it are described here on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Drupal folder and download it again. Don't forget to drop and create or truncate the DB.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope everything's going fine.